# conditional statement in menuitem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, conditional-statements, menuitem

Please excuse my ignorance with my question, I've been a CF developer for 18 years, but I now have a project I am working on in asp.net VB for the first time.

I need to do a conditional in the menuitem so that menu links show up based on user role (admin,coordinator, instructor,learner).

What is the best way to do this?  Below is the menu code.  Text in brackets shows the conditions.

```
 <asp:Menu ID="MyMenu" runat="server" DynamichorizonalOffset="2"
                            ForeColor="#000E8F" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Width="50%" CssClass="verticalmenu" 
                                        Font-Size="11pt" OnMenuItemClick="MyMenu_MenuItemClick">
                            <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="IE8Fix" verticalPadding="2px" />
                            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="horizonalmenu" VerticalPadding="5px" />
                            <StaticMenuItemStyle verticalPadding="2px" ItemSpacing="2px" 
                                CssClass="horizonalmenu" />
                            <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="#7D00B6" />
                                        <Items>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Accounts/Menu.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Search/Register for Classes" Value="Search/Register for Classes" NavigateUrl="~/Registration/SearchCourses.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Transcript [For Learner Only]" Value="Transcript"  NavigateUrl="~/InserviceHistory/InserviceTranscript.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Request for In-Service Credit [For Learner Only]" Value="My Menu" NavigateUrl="~/InserviceCredit/IndividualRequest/InstructionalIndividualCreditRequest.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Users [Admin, Coord, Instr]" Value="My Menu">
<asp:MenuItem Text="Administrator [Admin only]" Value="My Menu">
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Coordinators [Admin and Coord only]" Value="My Menu">
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Add" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="My Menu"></asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
 </Items>
                                    </asp:Menu>
```

I have found two ways of doing conditionals yet no clue how to incorporate them, these are the examples I found (not coded for my menu example):

```
                                    ----Example 1 -----
                                <%     Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim message As String 

        If count = 0 Then
            message = "There are no items." 
        ElseIf count = 1 Then
            message = "There is 1 item." 
        Else
            message = "There are " & count & " items." 
                                    End If
                                    %>

                                    ----Example 2 ------

                                      <%
if(1==1)
{%>

html code

<% } 
else 
{
%>
NOt 1
<% } %>
```

Comment: If you are using web forms, I would use the code behind object model to add nodes to the menu dynamically based upon the users role.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the conditionally handling manually.  You do need to use the [web.sitemap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab(v=vs.140).aspx) to populate your menu though if you want the automatic security trimming.

See [Walkthrough: Filtering Site-Map Nodes Based on Security Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429(v=vs.140).aspx)

> A role is the name of a group of users. After establishing roles, you can assign individual user accounts to a role. You can restrict access to Web files and nodes in site maps based on roles.

And read up on the [SiteMapProvider.SecurityTrimmingEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.securitytrimmingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) Property.

> Gets a Boolean value indicating whether a site map provider filters site map nodes based on a user's role.

For example, if you wanted to restrict access to the Admin folder, you would put something like this in the Admin folder Web.Config file to restrict all users except users with Role Administrators.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What if I did want to do the conditionals in the menuitem code though.  How would I do that?